# Read text or CSV file and break into groups separated by space

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a `.csv` file with data as:

```
20
40
25

50
60
80

10
25
34
75
50

50
60
```

I need to read this file and create groups of numbers whenever a blank value is found. Hence, for the example above, it should become:

```py
final_list = [
    [20, 40, 25],
    [50, 60, 80],
    [10, 25, 34, 75, 50],
    [50, 60]
]
```

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read a csv file line by by line & than one blank string in the list, you can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open(r"codeMaster.csv") as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()

line = [i.strip() for i in line]

print([list(g) for k, g in groupby(line, key=bool) if k])
```

Gives #

```
[['20', '40', '25'], ['50', '60', '80'], ['10', '25', '34', '75', '50'], ['50', '60']]
```

More pythonic ##

```
with open(r"CodeMaster.csv") as fp:
    line = fp.readlines()

line = [i.strip() for i in line]
result = [[]]
for i in line:
    if not i:
        result.append([])
    else:
        result[-1].append(i)
print(result)
```

Also Gives #

```
[['20', '40', '25'], ['50', '60', '80'], ['10', '25', '34', '75', '50'], ['50', '60']]
```

Comment: worked great but still can't wrap my head around itertools.groupby. The documentation for it is not clear/great!

Comment: @CodeMaster added pure pythonic solution also...Try and play arround if you getting confused with `ittertools`